# Subtract two TDATETIME variables in Delphi and return the result in minutes

Tags: delphi, tdatetime

I have two `TDateTime` variables, like this:

```
s := StrToDateTime('03/03/2017 10:10:12');
e := StrToDateTime('04/04/2017 10:10:12');
```

I need to find out the difference between them, in `hh:mm:ss` format.

The `...Between()` functions are not helping me here.

Comment: What Delphi version? Some have the capability to do this available; others don't and require you to write something yourself.

Comment: How exactly not helping? What did you try so far?

Comment: the delphi version is 10 seattle, i tried subtract itself, then timespan but none of them return the total difference which somehow is correct because the result could be maybe 45 hours and 20 minutes and 25 seconds which is not a correct format for hour even if i get total difference is minute or second is good i can take care of the rest

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [DateUtils.SecondsBetween](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DateUtils.SecondsBetween) function:

```
Uses
  DateUtils,SysUtils;

function TimeDiffStr(const s1,s2: String): String;
var
  t1,t2: TDateTime;
  secs: Int64;
begin
  t1 := StrToDateTime(s1); 
  t2 := StrToDateTime(s2); 
  secs := SecondsBetween(t1,t2);
  Result := Format('%2.2d:%2.2d:%2.2d',[secs div SecsPerHour,(secs div SecsPerMin) mod SecPerMin,secs mod SecsPerMin]);
end;

begin
  WriteLn(TimeDiffStr('03/03/2017 10:10:12','04/04/2017 10:10:12'));
  ReadLn;
end.
```

From the number of seconds, calculate the hours,minutes and remaining seconds.

---

If you want the difference in minutes, use the [DateUtils.MinutesBetween](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DateUtils.MinutesBetween) function:

```
function TimeDiffStr(const s1,s2: String): String;
var
  t1,t2: TDateTime;
  minutes: Int64;
begin
  t1 := StrToDateTime(s1); 
  t2 := StrToDateTime(s2); 
  minutes := MinutesBetween(t1,t2);
  Result := Format('%2.2d:%2.2d:%2.2d',[minutes div MinsPerHour,minutes mod MinsPerHour,0]);
end;
```

Comment: You should use the constants in the `SysUtils` unit instead of using "magic numbers" directly in code, eg: `Result := Format('%2.2d:%2.2d:%2.2d',[secs div SecsPerHour, (secs div SecsPerMin) mod SecsPerMin, secs mod SecsPerMin]);` and `Result := Format('%2.2d:%2.2d:%2.2d', [minutes div MinsPerHour, minutes mod MinsPerHour, 0]);`
`

Comment: @RemyLebeau, yes that makes sense, corrected. Thanks.

Comment: this one works too but why in the help it says this function returns only the difference of the seconds i have no idea

Comment: oh no i think i really lost in the code and help, i think i got it wrong, because i was looking for something so difficult and impossible

Comment: @TinaSoltanian: you are misreading what the documentation is actually saying. `SecondsBetween()` returns the total difference between the two date/time values, expressed in whole seconds.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [TTimeSpan](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TimeSpan.TTimeSpan) (from the System.TimeSpan unit).

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.TimeSpan;

var
  StartDate, EndDate: TDateTime;
  TS: TTimeSpan;
  Temp: string;
begin
  StartDate := StrToDateTime('03/03/2017 10:10:12');
  EndDate := StrToDateTime('04/04/2017 10:10:12');
  TS := TTimeSpan.Subtract(EndDate, StartDate);
  Temp := TS;
  WriteLn(Temp);  // Outputs 32.00:00:00
  // The next line outputs the same as the one above
  WriteLn(Format('%.2d:%.2d:%.2d:%.2d', [TS.Days, TS.Hours, TS.Minutes, TS.Seconds]));
  WriteLn(TS.TotalMinutes); // Outputs 4.60800000000000E+0004
  WriteLn(Trunc(TS.TotalMinutes)); // Outputs 46080

  // This one will give the output you want (768:00:00)
  WriteLn(Format('%.2d:%.2d:%.2d', [TS.Days * 24 + TS.Hours, TS.Minutes, TS.Seconds]));
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: Shouldn't you swap the `StartDate` and `EndDate` parameters? `TS := TTimeSpan.Subtract(EndDate, StartDate);`  That is equivalent to `EndDate - StartDate`.

Comment: @Remy: Caught that. On the phone right now; will edit in a few.

Comment: @Remy: Updated. (My mother hates it when I put her on speaker.)

Comment: this is awesome, thank you so much, i really have no idea why all the things that i tested was not working, when Im tired im kind of getting lost in codes. any way thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

First off, don't use hard-coded strings for date/time values.  That is subject to localization issues, and it is just wasted overhead anyway.  Use the `SysUtils.EncodeDate()` and `SysUtils.EncodeTime()` functions, or the `DateUtils.EncodeDateTime()` function.

Second, the `...Between()` functions can indeed be usedneed, in particular `SecondsBetween()`.  You can calculate the individual components from that return value.

Try something like this:

```
uses
  ..., SysUtils, DateUtils;

var
  s, e: TDateTime;
  diff: Int64;
  days, hours, mins, secs: Integer;
  s: string;
begin
  s := EncodeDateTime(2017, 3, 3, 10, 10, 12, 0);
  e := EncodeDateTime(2017, 4, 4, 10, 10, 12, 0);

  diff := SecondsBetween(e, s);

  days := diff div SecsPerDay;
  diff := diff mod SecsPerDay;

  hours := diff div SecsPerHour;
  diff := diff mod SecsPerHour;

  mins := diff div SecsPerMin;
  diff := diff mod SecsPerMin;

  secs := diff;

  s := Format('%d:%d:%d:%d', [days, hours, mins, secs]);
end;
```

Comment: but as far as i read the seconds between just return the difference of seconds not the total difference

Comment: @TinaSoltanian: That is not true. `SecondsBetween()` returns the total number of whole seconds between the two date/time values.  That takes minutes/hours/days/years into account. Same goes for the other `...Between()` functions.

Comment: yeahhh thank you so muchhhh, you all helped me a lot. now i can complete my code